# Ada I/O: Put_Line not working after Get_Line

Tags: console-application, ada

I'm trying to do basic I/O in Ada, but the documentation on this isn't very informative (unless I'm going to the wrong place). In the following block, I was trying to test string appending and output, but for some reason it literally only outputs "Hello WORLD!" I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but I have been trying for a few hours to figure this out.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings.Fixed;


procedure Main is

     usrIn : String(1..80);
     appendString : Unbounded_String;
     last : Natural;

begin
     Put_Line ("Hello WORLD!");
     Get_Line(usrIn, last);
     Put_Line ("AAAAAAAA");
     appendString := To_Unbounded_String("USER IN: ");
     Append(appendString,usrIn);
     Put_Line("Output follows");
     Put_Line(To_String(appendString));

end Main;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`usrIn` is a `String(1..80)`, i.e., an array of 80 characters.

This line:

```
Append(appendString,usrIn);
```

appends all 80 characters (most of which are likely garbage) to `appendString`.

This is what the `last` argument to `Get_Line` is for.

Replace `userIn` by `userIn(userIn'First .. last)`. That's a slice that consists only of the characters read by the `Get_Line` call.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you! 
I am curious though, why was "AAAAAAAA" not being printed, even though it's before the erroring line?

Comment: It’s printed here (macOS). I’d have expected `Put_Line` to flush output, at any rate if to the console, but maybe you need to call `Flush`?

Comment: @NikonJR: It's printed on my system too (Ubuntu). If you're curious, you might consider posting a question with the exact code that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are compiling using a version in Ada 2005 or more, you can also use the function form of [`Get_Line`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Text_IO) :

```
declare
    usrIn : constant String := Get_Line;
begin
    Append(appendString,usrIn);
end;
```